# React native dev tools does not work in android emulator

Tags: android, react-native, android-virtual-device

I used to open the react native dev tools on my android emulator (AVD) using ctrl+M.

But lately it stopped working.

I have tried to change the android keyset but it didn't help.

I put a breakpoint inside the java code and I noticed that I didn't get key pressed event for ctrl+M or other control keys (I got for other keys).

I am using UBUNTU 14.0.4, android SDK manager 25.1.6, react native 0.24.1.

Please help.

Thanks